Discord py sticker upload issues
I have a Union list of discord.PartialEmoji and discord.Sticker and i iterate them into CDN asset to preview like this

        if isinstance(emoji, discord.PartialEmoji):

            self.url = emoji.url

        else:

            self.url = f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/stickers/{emoji.id}.png"

And now i want to upload these as a sticker in guild it could be either using object or CDN link
I've already tried this with emojis
Code:

emoji = data[index]

name = emoji.name.replace(" ", "_") # i have to replace whitespace when it's a sticker

emoji = await ctx.guild.create_custom_emoji(name=name, image=await emoji.read())

And there's a slight issue with that whenever i upload animated sticker in this it gets uploaded as a static
